# Как достать link канала telegram из TdApi?

Tags: telegram

Не могу получить ссылку типа `https://t.me/...` из *TdApi*.

Есть доступ к апи, могу получить `id` канала, но не могу достать название, которое обычно пишут через `@`.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод GetSupergroup принимает id типа int, в котором содержится поле username, то что я и искал